# How to Scrape Dynamic Website in Go?

Tags: go

With NodeJS I can use PhantomJS to help me to scrape dynamic website, with Python I can use Selenium to do this job.

How about in GoLang?

Comment: You can use selenium with go as well: google for "go webdriver" and pick the library you like more.

Answer (score 3):

Give it a try on Go lang selenium web drivers

https://github.com/knq/chromedp : Package chromedp is a faster, simpler way to drive browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari, Android, etc) without external dependencies (ie, Selenium, PhantomJS, etc) using the Chrome Debugging Protocol.

https://github.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium : Selenium WebDriver client for Go

https://github.com/tebeka/selenium : Selenium/Webdriver client for Go

---

Static Crawler Reference

You can use `github.com/PuerkitoBio/gocrawl` library or built your custom crawler, basic idea is here https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/10.

Comment: yes, but not dynamic